# latex/mathml to doc file using asp.net web api 2

Tags: latex, asp.net-web-api2, docx, mathml

I am try to export **latex/Mathml to word document** using asp.net web api 2.

but no luck.

I knew when we paste `mathml` format into word file it's convert to it's respected equestion. But how can I create word file from web api which be is proper equestions format ?

like I have mathml as string :

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></math>
```

when I export this into Word doc, its give me same string as it is.
But I am trying to convert this into mathametic's equestions like below :

[image]

thanks in advance.